# In AEM, how do I proetect asset from anonymous access?

Tags: aem

This is what I want to do, in AEM, there are some sensitive PDFs links on the page. So when people click these pdf links, I want to let the user to login first. After that, they can view these PDFs assets. Right now, all the PDFs are in the DAM. I may need to override some OTB pages that load the assets, but I just can't figure out which page I should override...

Can someone shed some light on this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure privileges of users on assets folder, or specific asset folder. [Read more about users preveleges here](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/administering/security.html)

Answer (score 0):

The AEM term is CUG or "Closed User Group" for resources that require authentication to access.  Anonymous users requesting a resource in a CUG will be redirected to the login form (which you can also modify).

- https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/howto/create_apply_cug.html
- https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/administer/security/cug.html

(depending on which version you are working on).